# Python to remove extra delimiter

Tags: python, csv

We have a 100MB pipe delimited file that has 5 column/4 delimiters each separated by a pipe. However there are few rows where the second column has an extra pipe. For these few rows total delimiter are 5.

For example, in the below 4 rows, the 3rd is a problematic one as it has an extra pipe.

```
1|B|3|D|5
A|1|2|34|5
D|This is a |text|3|5|7
B|4|5|5|6
```

Is there any way we can remove an extra pipe from the second position where the delimiter count for the row is 5. So, post correction, the file needs to look like below.

```
1|B|3|D|5
A|1|2|34|5
D|This is a text|3|5|7
B|4|5|5|6
```

Please note that the file size is 100 MB. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So will the extra pipe always occur in the same 'column'? Similarly, in your example it is in a text field. Is that always going to be the case?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, it will always be in the second column. It can also be two numbers separated by a extra pipe or a combination of text and number separated by a extra pipe, or just text separated by extra pipe

Comment: I think 'is there Any way' is a too vague a question for Stackoverflow's format.  The answer is 'iterate over the file, detect the lines with the extra pipe and delete it,'  did you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: my_file.txt

```
1|B|3|D|5
A|1|2|34|5
D|This is a |text|3|5|7
B|4|5|5|6
E|1 |9 |2 |8 |Not| a |text|!!!|3|7|4
```

Code

```
# If using Python3.10, this can be Parenthesized context managers
# https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#parenthesized-context-managers
with open('./my_file.txt') as file_src, open('./my_file_parsed.txt', 'w') as file_dst:
    for line in file_src.readlines():
        # Split the line by the character '|'
        line_list = line.split('|')

        if len(line_list) <= 5:
            # If the number of columns doesn't exceed, just write the original line as is.
            file_dst.write(line)
        else:
            # If the number of columns exceeds, count the number of columns that should be merged.
            to_merge_columns_count = (len(line_list) - 5) + 1
            # Merge the columns from index 1 to index x which includes all the columns to be merged.
            merged_column = "".join(line_list[1:1+to_merge_columns_count])
            # Replace all the items from index 1 to index x with the single merged column
            line_list[1:1+to_merge_columns_count] = [merged_column]

            # Write the updated line.
            file_dst.write("|".join(line_list))
```

Result: my_file_parsed.txt

```
1|B|3|D|5
A|1|2|34|5
D|This is a text|3|5|7
B|4|5|5|6
E|1 9 2 8 Not a text!!!|3|7|4
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple regular expression pattern like this works on Python 3.7.3:

```py
from re import compile


bad_pipe_re = compile(r"[ \w]+\|[ \w]+(\|)[ \w]+\|[ \w]+\|[ \w]+\|[ \w]+\n")


with open("input", "r") as fp_1, open("output", "w") as fp_2:
    line = fp_1.readline()
    while line is not "":
        mo = bad_pipe_re.fullmatch(line)
        if mo is not None:
            line = line[:mo.start(1)] + line[mo.end(1):]
        fp_2.write(line)
        line = fp_1.readline()
```